# Checking if element is a 0 or any other value in Scala

Tags: list, scala, set

I have a box made up of a list of lists in Scala and I need to check if a particular cell contains an element that is not 0 or a 0 (given the row and column index to access that cell). If the element found is not a 0, an empty set should be returned else another value which I managed to code should be returned. How can I check if a particular cell contains 0 or not?
Code so far:

```
 if(//cell does not contain 0) 
   Set()
 else
 {
   //this part of code is ready
 }
```

Comment: if `box` is `List[List[Int]]`, and you have `row`, `col` you can access element as `box(row)(col)`. you can compare that to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in a comment, just use `box(i)(j)`.

Moreover, I would suggest to create at least a type alias for your box

```
type Box = List[List[Int]]
```

or a case class if you want to add methods like `getValue(row: Int, col: Int) : Int`

```
case class Box(val l: List[List[Int]])
```

Comment: `List[Int][Int]` is just not valid scala. Did you try to compile this code?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet fix